# The Great Art Theft

Tags: cipher, visual, story, knowledge

The day was March 18, 1990. Just a few hours ago, [multiple valuable artworks were stolen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabella_Stewart_Gardner_Museum_theft) by men in fake uniforms. You, a famous code breaker, happened to stumble upon two pieces of evidences that the criminals left at the crime scene. From various lead, you also knew that on Friday, the perpetrators are going to meet in a location somewhere in Boston to discuss the price of the artworks in the black market. Going of these evidences, how can you find the time and location that the thefts will meet?

**Evidence 1:**

A standard newspaper article:

[image]

**Evidence 2:**

A jigsaw puzzle, but all the pieces are shuffled.

[image]

**Evidence 3:**

A piece of paper that has the following letters written in pencils:

> **NHNTTMZNHVRK**
>
> Five RC

Comment: Something you apparently aren't aware of is, that trying to solve your jigsaw puzzle on a computer by cutting out the pieces and rotating them into a correct position would be a major PITA, which most people won't bother to do.

Comment: @Sleafar Could it be that the jigsaw is [rot13](https://rot13.com/)(npghnyyl abg vagraqrq gb or er-cbfvgvbarq naq zrnaf fbzrguvat ryfr vafgrnq)?

Comment: I love the fact about Franklin. I would enjoy seeing all eagles in American iconography replaced by turkeys.

Answer (score 6):

I can at least give you a time:

> **10 PM**

I found this by:

> Seeing that "Joana V" is an anagram of "Navajo". as it turns out, each fact references a letter in the Navajo Code Talker alphabet: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_talker#Navajo_code_talkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_talker#Navajo_code_talkers)
>  The words are Turkey, Elk, Nut, Pig and Mouse. In order, they translate to TEN PM.

Now for the location...

Answer (score 4):

**Jigsaw**

> [image]
>  D Y U M T
>  F R E K H
>  W L I Q B
>  V O C P X
>  A G S Z N

Perhaps it will be used for

> a Playfair cipher or something of the kind. But for what it's worth, using the Playfair tool at http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/playfair.php and that square doesn't appear to turn NHNTTMZNHVRK into anything useful. ... Well, more specifically it yields XTXNMUSZFXFE, which does have suspiciously many Xs in it; they might be padding, stand-ins for repeated letters, etc., but looking at (say) "T NMUSZF FE" nothing jumps out at me. Bobson, in comments, implies that some other way of Playfairing it yields something with a different variety of suspicious exiness, but I'm not sure what other way. If I run the same letters *forward* through the same tool, I get TBTHDTNAFXEH which doesn't seem interesting.

Comment: I wonder if the specific piece of art used is relevant in any way. Any idea what it is?

Comment: It's called "The Dutch Proverbs" and was painted by Pieter Breugel the Elder in 1559.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlandish_Proverbs

Comment: It doesn't appear to have been one of the artworks stolen in the (real) heist mentioned in the puzzle.

Comment: You think there are any proverbs to go with the animals in the article? It seems like "Joana V" can anagram to "Navajo"...and all of those animals show up in the Navajo code talker alphabet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_talker#Navajo_code_talkers

Comment: Running NHNTTMZNHVRK through this grid as Playfair produces a string that looks a lot like a message prepped for Playfair encryption.  There's an X separating a double letter, and a spare X at the end.  It's possible there should be another transform on the result based on "Five RC" to get the final value.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the Xs and wondered whether something of the kind was going on. Haven't tried hard to figure out what it might be.

Comment: Though the obvious interpretation of "Five RC" is simply "five rows and columns" which would tell us nothing new.

Comment: No, wait, I think we are seeing different X-related oddities. How do you get an X separating a pair of double letters etc.?